# How to automatically download all new images appearing on a newsfeed on Facebook

Tags: image, facebook, photo, download

I am attempting to write a script or make a FB App to automatically download images from profiles on Facebook at a designated time during the day, and have it repeat each day. After this is accomplished I aim to implement the reverse of this to upload images within an album to a profile, but that will be for another day. These are going to be profiles that I am friends with, or public profiles.

Having some issues determining where to start as it seems this isn't done on a regular. Can anyone provide a direction for me to head in? I have looked into the Facebook Developers website, as well as on stack overflow and haven't seem to find any solution that is close. I have stumbled upon examples on how to autodownload from Reddit, but Facebook is another beast entirely it seems.

Is this something that can be accomplished via Java or Python, or should I actually go through the Facebook API? At a bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

ANY help would be appreciated as I am not a web developer. I mostly dabble with MATLAB and Java so this is a bit outside of my expertise.

Once again to summarize, I am seeking to auto download images from Facebook profiles either as they are posted or at selected times. Also this idea could be changed to download from Instagram if that is somehow easier.

Comment: It is not possible to do using the API because the API doesn't allow you to do it. And Facebook does not allow you to scrape them

Comment: any data of users who did not specifically authorize your app is none of your business and not available with the api. data of friends of an authorized user is off limits as well. also, posting photos to user profiles is not possible anymore. what you want to do is not possible and scraping is not allowed. rule of thumb: if it´s not possible with the official api, it´s not allowed.